# Editable MS Access Query with varchar fields in join is no more editable when backend upgraded to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, inner-join, varchar

I upgraded back-end MS Access 2003 to MySQL 5.1 of a database. Now I am linking the backend MYSQL 5.1 database thr' ODBC (MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver) to MS Access using ODBC.

Almost all features worked fine when I set the indexes, primary key relationship/constraints etc.

But one below query which was editable in MS Access version before back-end upgrade, is no more allowing edits.

The join type is Left/Inner/Right Join and fields in join are varchar data type.

```
SELECT tblebayinvoices.[User Id], tblebayinvoices.[Buyer Full name], tblebayinvoices.  
[Buyer Phone Number],  tblstock.stcEBayDescr, tblstock.stcEBayActive
FROM tblebayinvoices LEFT JOIN tblstock ON tblebayinvoices.[Item Title] = 
tblstock.stcEBayDescr;
```

My observation is other queries where the field data type is numberic, they are fine and the queries are still editable. This same query was editable when the back-end was MS Access
I tried using Text data type of MySQL but MS Access treats this as Memo and does not allow using in joins.

Please let me know suggestions or changes I need to do.

Comment: Are the primary keys defined for both of the tables

Comment: @Linger , yes both the tables have primary respective. and other indexed fields as those were in MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating unique key on "stcEBayDescr" solved the problem. We missed the unique key index that was there in MS Access but not created in MySQL table's database. 
Now the query is editable in MS Access(uses MySQL linked tables thr' MySQL ODBC)

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that your joined fields are the primary keys.  I am assuming this since those fields are text and don't appear to be typical primary key fields.

The join will only be editable if the join is done from a primary key on the
main table to the foreign key in the child table.

Comment: 1) The text fields on which I am making joins are not primary keys, but each table has one other numeric field as primary key respectively.
2) The same query works in MS Access without any changes to primary key, I am confused why so ? It is just that data is in MS Access and in above case tables are in MySQL linked to MS Access thr' ODBC.

Comment: Different databases handle this scenario differently.  That is why database design should always link tables via primary and foreign keys.  If the only way you can link `tblebayinvoices` to `tblstock` is via `[Item Title]` and `stcEBayDescr`, then you may not be able to update the data directly via the query.  You could however, create a temporary table to dump the query into and then make your changes.  Once done open the tables separately and edit based on the table.

Comment: Making a temporary table and updating back to respective tables looks good option. Since application is used in Multi-user scenario, I am afraid how good this can be implemented.

 Now I am checking whether MySQL gives any facility like stored proc or function which I can use for editing data using this Query's SQL. Further to this, I need to investigate whether such stored proce/function can be linked thr' ODBC to front-end MS Access application.

Comment: Throwing the results into a table is pretty quick as long as you are not working with a huge data set.  The updating of records could be handled per field instead of per record.  If handled this way, the conflict of two users writing to the same record would only be fractions of a second.  Then the likelihood of a conflict would be very rare.

Comment: This query is editable thr' dbForge studio express for MySQL.  The problem must be in the ODBC driver.  Due to MySQL ODBC connection query gives non editable record set that has joins but not primary key. I am searching alternative to MySQL ODBC to link tables to MS Access.